# Sed: how to turn a backreference into a variable name?

Tags: regex, sed

Do you know how I could use a backreference as a variable name, in sed?

What I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
var_one=x
var_two=y
var_three=z
echo "var_one + var_two = var_three" | sed -e "s/\(var_[^\ ]*\)/$\1/g"
```

What I got:

```
$var_one + $var_two = $var_three
```

What I want to get:

```
x + y = z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Expand Variables with Eval

It's not clear what you're really trying to do, but if all you want to do is *create* some variables in a string, and then evaluate the string to expand the variables, then you want to use *eval*. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
var_one=x
var_two=y
var_three=z
result=$(
    echo "var_one + var_two = var_three" |
    sed -e "s/\(var_[^\ ]*\)/$\1/g"
)
eval "echo $result"
```

There are a lot of pitfalls involved with using *eval*. However, this code certainly solves the problem you've described.